# How to retry with different url if request returns an error

Tags: angular, rxjs, nestjs

I have a request that looks like this:

```
  private getData(param) {
    const url = (name: string) =>
      `https://website.com/${name}/data`;

    return this.http.get<Data>(url(param));
  }
```

when the request return an error I want to retry but with another param.
How can you do that?

I am able to catch an error like this

```
  private getData(param) {
    const url = (name: string) =>
      `https://website.com/${name}/data`;

    return this.http.get<Data>(url(param)).pipe(
       catchError(error => of(error))
    );
  }
```

But how would you retry with different url?

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `catchError` is an `observable`. If you just want to make a new request, you can replace the error observable with your new request. Like this.

```
const example = source.pipe(
  catchError(val => {
    return of(`new request result`)
  }));
//output: 'new request result'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but can you try it like this?

```
 private getData(param) {
    const url = (name: string) =>
      `https://website.com/${name}/data`;
     const anotherUrl = (name: string) =>
      `https://website.com/${name}/data`;

    return this.http.get<Data>(url(param)).pipe(
       catchError(error => of(error){
            this.http.get<Data>(anotherUrl(param)).pipe(
              catchError(error => of(error))
       })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I will try like this

```
class UserService {
  private getData(param, tried=3) {
    const url = (name: string) => {
      `https:///website.com/${name}/data`;
    }

    return this.http.get<Data>(url(param)).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (tried < 0) {
        throw error;
      }
      // assign name, param's property as a new value
      param.name = 'newName';
      // then, call again with param with another name 
      // while tried counter to be 0
      this.getData(param, tried - 1);
    }));  
  }
}
```

1. Add a new parameter `tried` to `getData` method to handle infinite loop of retrying. And set it's default value as 3(Maybe 5, 7, what else as you like)
2. Use your method which using the `http` method of `NestJS` and `.pipe`.
3. Then If this request got an error, retried to the renewed parameter with another name, like assigning `param.name = 'newName'` I wrote.
4. Call this `getData` method recursively with dicsount -1 from the `tried` parameter.

May this helps you.